# How to use Map<String,dynamic> type json in Flutter

Tags: json, dart

part of codes:

```
class ListVideo extends StatelessWidget {

  final Map < String,dynamic > list;

  ListVideo({this.list});

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new ListView.builder(
        itemCount: list == null ? 0 : list.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, i){
          return new Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new GestureDetector(
                  onTap: ()=>Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context)=>new VideoPlay(url: "https://youtube.com/embed/$list[i]['contentDetails']['videoId']",))),
                  child: new Container(
                    height: 210.0,
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      image: new DecorationImage(
                          image: new NetworkImage(
                              list['items'][i]['snippet']['thumbnails']['high']['url']),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover)
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                new Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),),
                new Text(list[i]['snippet']['title'],style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),),
                new Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),),
                new Divider(),
              ],
            ),
          );
    },
    );
  }
}
```

Originally list's type is not Map< String,dynamic > But List

but JSON is changed

from:
json : `array[9]->arrayindex, ex) 0 ->snippet{9}`

-above case, I can access list[i]['snippet']~

to:
json : `object{4} -> items[9] -> [arrayindex] -> snippet{9}`

Originally list's type is not Map But List, List code is working well

but JSON is changed

from: `json : array[9] -> arrayindex, ex) 0 -> snippet{9}`

-----Above case, I can access like:  list[i]['snippet']~

to: `json : object{4} -> items[9] -> arrayindex -> snippet{9}`

how can I access to 'snippet', using new JSON and Map type?

-sorry, I'm not good at English.

when JSON is changed like above flutter console said some error so I searched google and change type List to Map< String,dynamic >, if I don't have to use that. that also a good solution.